# Twig if statement not working for extends

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to differentiate between a user browsing the website and a user accessing the website from outside so I would like to use a if statement to load or not the homepage which has all the structure HTML.

Instead of making a POST and a GET route I would like to use a if statement in the TWIG template but it is not working; the homepage always gets loaded

I tried `false` and `'false'`

here is my `itemListing.html.twig`

```
{% if ajax == false %}

   {% extends 'homepage.html.twig' %}

{% endif %}

{% block content %}

    {% for item in items %}

         code

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

and the php code

```
return $this->render('itemSearch/itemListing.html.twig',[
    'ajax' => true,
]);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you seem to be sending along `ajax => false` and then in your twig template you check `if ajax == false`, which will ofcourse evaluate to true, so your homepage gets loaded. Maybe you want to check if it's true instead of false?

Comment: sorry just bad example, I'll update the question, I just have one with true and one with false in my controller depending if it is ajax or not

Comment: Shouldn't the extends tag be the first tag in the template ? And then you could override / display the parent's blocks according to your if condition.

Comment: @Elbarto the extend is precisely what I want to avoid if it is ajax, the rest should always be displayed but I'll probably have to put the `block` tags in a if statement too since they can only exist with extend I think

Comment: i guess it is not possible the way you want it to, there wont be any blocks if nothing is extended... you should rather check in controller if it is xmlHttp request or check the request method

Comment: That is my point, you could just extend the template no matter what, and then in your if statement, list all the blocks with their content, to remove any content just write an empty block, and if you want the parent's one go for {{parent() }} inside a block

Comment: I get your point but regardless the if statement is not working. If it was working I would have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the dynamic inheritance of extend
or conditional inheritance, you could do sth like this:

```
{% extends ajax ? "minimum.html" : "base.html" %}
```

Comment: seems to work for the `else` but I need a nothing in the first statement. I tried `{% extends ajax ? "" : "homepage.html.twig" %}` but I get error on ajax `true`. Can we work around that ?

Comment: Not very pretty but I just created a `dummy.html.twig` with a single twig block in it and it works. `{% extends ajax ? "dummy.html.twig" : "homepage.html.twig" %}` again, not pretty. Is it possible to do your expression without the first argument ?

Comment: a pretty approach in my opinion would not seperate on the template-layer you should differenciate on controller-layer or even routing as i stated in my comment, but as long as it works... ;-)

Comment: IMO all other differentiation methods create more code and also unnecessary duplicates. If you make more routes you have more methods and more templates, and if you have more templates; well.. you have more templates... I think this is a TWIG shortcoming at the moment but Im new to symfony... Twig should allow for easy optional `extends`